# IGNORE not working Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hi i am importing a csv through a script 
the table structure is as below

```
`contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contact_first` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `contact_last` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`)
```

and the data in csv is like this

```
Jim,Smith,jim@tester.com
Joe,Tester,joe@tester.com
```

and the query i am using for insert is as below

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                )
            ");
```

i have made use of ignore function in the query but it doesnot work and it keeep on onserting the same value

Answer (score 0):

The `IGNORE` keyword will only have your desired impact on duplicate rows.

A row will only be recognized as a duplicate if you have a primary key or unique key on the appropriate columns.

You haven't really explained exactly what the issue is, but I suspect you might want to create a unique key on the `contact_email` column to prevent duplicates from being inserted.

I would also suggest at a minimum using `mysql_escape_string` instead of `addslashes` to ensure the strings are encoded correctly.

There will likely be comments on the fact that the mysql_* functions are deprecated so you should look into PDO or mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead
Refer [DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

The use of **IGNORE** is :

`If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.`

in your case you are inserting three values which are same but as the ID is `auto incremental`  which will insert new record with same values which is obvious.
If you want to prevent it from inserting in to the database you have to add unique index to one of the other column

hope it will help!